Distribution of indices of corresponding order statistics of sequence of random variables
Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of i.i.d real-valued random variables. For every realization of the sequence, there exists a permutation $\sigma : \{ 1,..., n\} \to \{ 1,...,n\}$ such that $X_{\sigma(1)} \leq X_{\sigma(2)} \leq ... \leq X_{\sigma(n)}$. Given some other conditions, suppose that we can make the random permutation $\sigma$ obtained in this sense unique.
What is this type of random permutation called? Is the joint distribution of $(\sigma(1), \sigma(2),..., \sigma(n))$ known for fixed $n$, or possibly some limiting properties of the joint distribution as $n \to \infty$ known?

If you have continuous iid random variables there is probability $1$ that the $n$ values are distinct and so that there is exactly one permutation of them in the desired order.  But I am unclear what you are asking.

As Henry intimates in his comment, if $\ X_i\ $ are continuous random variables, then
\begin{align}
1&=P\left(\bigcup_{\sigma\in S_n}\big\{X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\dots<X_{\sigma(n)}\big\}\right)\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}P\big(X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\dots<X_{\sigma(n)}\big)\\
&=n!P\big(X_{\rho(1)}<X_{\rho(2)}<\dots<X_{\rho(n)}\big)
\end{align}
for any $\ \rho\in S_n\ ,$ because the events $\ \big\{X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\dots<X_{\sigma(n)}\big\}\ $ and $\ \big\{X_{\rho(1)}<X_{\rho(2)}<\dots<X_{\rho(n)}\big\}\ $ are mutually exclusive for $\ \rho\ne\sigma\ ,$ and it follows from the fact that the $\ X_i\ $ are independent and identically distributed that $\ P\big(X_{\rho(1)}<X_{\rho(2)}<\dots<X_{\rho(n)}\big)=$$\,P\big(X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\dots<X_{\sigma(n)}\big)\ .$  Thus
$$
P\big(X_{\rho(1)}<X_{\rho(2)}<\dots<X_{\rho(n)}\big)=\frac{1}{n!}
$$
for all $\ \rho\in S_n\ .$ Thus, the random permutation $\ \sigma\ $ almost surely defined by the condition
$$
X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\dots<X_{\sigma(n)}
$$
will be  uniformly distributed over $\ S_n\ .$
